# How to access same DbContext instances in nested Blazor Components?

Tags: c#, concurrency, blazor-server-side

My Blazor components are nested as follows:

```
<ProjectDashboard>
     <DashboardLoginPartial >
              <Notification/>
     <DashboardLoginPartial />
     <MessageBoard/>
<ProjectDashboard/>
```

I keep getting these errors :
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance.
or
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed

What is the best way to go about this as I need to access the same Db Context in ProjectDashboard, Notification and MessageBoard Components.

Basically all but DashboardLoginPartial Components are calling the Db Context inside the OnInitializedAsync() method.

Comment: Resolve db context factory and create a new context instance.